# Regex expression matching strings

Tags: c#, regex

What input string will the following regex expression match:

```
[1-4]{0-5}
```

I know the first part: `[1-4]` specifies the numerals allowed in the input, and the latter the length? But it does not match any of the expected inputs, such as `1112, 123`..

Comment: The way you've changed the question makes the existing answers look very odd. If that pattern really isn't matching "1112" please provide a [mcve] so we can try to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following regex,

It should be :

```
[1-4]{0,5}
```

This will match:

```
empty string  = because {0,5} means zero to 5 length of character
1
11
111
1111
11111
2
22
2222

1
12
1234
12344
and it goes on and on but nothing beyond the digit 4, and no length beyond 5
```

> [Regex101Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aRdMLY/2/)

Answer (score 3):

The latter is not the length. If it were the length, it would be `{0,5}` with a *comma* instead of a `-`.

Without the comma, it will just match `{0-5}` literally, so this matches:

```
1{0-5}
```

I think you want

```
[1-4]{0,5}
```